# If G is a connected graph and C is a cycle from G, my question is: G-C is connected graph?

Tags: graph-theory

If G is a connected graph and C is a cycle from G, my question is: G-C is connected graph? This question is related with clasiffication surfaces theorem. If the Euler characteristic is lower than 2, then exist a simple curve and not separed the surface. Thank's

Comment: whats style in graph theory’s context?

Comment: A graph can be embedded into a surface. Therefore a triangulation can see like a graph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends. If you remove the edges of a [wheel graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_graph) that are not adjacent to the universal vertex, what remains is connected. If you remove the edges of the cycle in the graph shown below, what remains is not connected.

```
                       *
                       |
                       *
                      / \
                     *   *
                      \ /
                       *
                       |
                       *
```

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: @MATHCOACHING: You’re very welcome.